# Set the style of ::after to be equal to the style of the selected element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, jsx

I use SCSS with css-modules in my React app and need to set the color of ::after element based on backgroundColor of the selected element, which receives it through JSX style prop.

**JSX element:**

```
<span 
    afterColor={myBackgroundColor}
    className={className} 
    style={{ myBackgroundColor, myColor }}
>Text</span>
```

**className variable:**

```
className = [scss.classOne, scss.classTwo].join(' ')
```

**Styles:**

```
.className::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: myBackgroundColor transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

**QUESTION:**
How to access myBackgroundColor (of the element that ::after is used with)?

P.S. Yes, `::after` creates pointer of a tooltip.

Comment: You can't manipulate :after or change its color, its not part of the actual dom, you will have to change the className to a different class with a different after psudo class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control the properties of a pseudo elements via Javascript directly by changing the `style` property for example. However, you can change properties indirectly via inheritance, and CSS variables. Other options (which are not demonstrated in this answer) include `currentColor`, and changing the stylesheet rules.

### **Inheritance:**

The `::after` pseudo element can inherit the border color (and other properties) of it's parent using the CSS keyword [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit).

> The inherit CSS keyword causes the element for which it is specified
>   to take the computed value of the property from its parent element.

**Example:**

```js
const Tooltip = ({ myBackgroundColor, children }) => (
  <div className="tooltip" style={{ 
    background: myBackgroundColor,
    borderColor: myBackgroundColor // set the borderColor as well
  }}>{ children }</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tooltip myBackgroundColor="red">Text</Tooltip>,
  demo
);
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px;
}

.tooltip::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

---

### **CSS Variables:**

If you need more control over the `::after` CSS properties, you can use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). You can set the background color of the tooltip, and the border color of the `::after` element to a variable, and then update the variable via JS (React in this case).

*Note:* CSS variables are not support by IE. React supports CSS variables in the style prop since version [5.6.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1560-june-13-2017).

**Example:**

```js
const Tooltip = ({ myBackgroundColor, afterBackgroundColor, children }) => (
  <div className="tooltip" style={{ 
    '--afterColor': afterBackgroundColor, 
    background: myBackgroundColor 
  }}>{ children }</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tooltip myBackgroundColor="red" afterBackgroundColor="blue">Text</Tooltip>,
  demo
);
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px;
}

.tooltip::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: var(--afterColor);
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```